# Looking for suggestions on best stack to use for my public facing site and app

Tags: javascript

**I am wondering the best way to serve my site and app.** Maybe I am over thinking it. **I am building a website and app for my medical billing and coding company as well as my medical marijuana doctor office.** I am trying to figure out the best way to set everything up and the best stack to use.

**I am pretty sure I am going with a mean app for the health records, scheduling, and payment system with aws app sync.**

**My questions are about the public facing website mostly. I want it to be a multipage site with a schedular on the front. The public facing site is live now.** maryjanehs.com It is just a static plain html css site for now. I need to implement a templating engine and am wanting to use ejs, maybe something more current but I have used ejs before, not set in stone and open for suggestions.

**How would the stack look. I think I am over thinking it but there are so many options it is making my head go in circles.**

Whats the best way to set up the front end. Is ejs or something similar the best route. I want to stay away from angular and SPAs on the public facing site since these are local businesses and I want to maximize SEO and need multiple pages.

Page speed is very important too. I am good with wordpress but it seems like such an overkill now especially since it is so slow on mobil when you use third party themes and plugins.

I can also use spring boot java and thymeleaf but I would really like to stick to javascript and the likes.

Comment: Where will it run? Browser only? Native app on Android, IoS, Windows, Linux, Mac?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. It will be browser only for now with the hopes of creating a native after the web app is optimized.

Comment: I only asked, because [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) by Goolge currently produces native apps for IoS & Android, from the same source base, plus n Alpha Mac desktop & Technical Preview for Windows & Linux. So, write your code once & soon enough it will run on all of those natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to a conclusion. I have an AWS Lightsail server running a node stack and I used handlebars for templating.

And then I have an AWS Lightsail server running a MEAN stack.

The servers are very inexpensive, I am very comfortable with AWS, and it will be easy to expand.

Posting here still helped. I have been going around in circles trying to figure out what was the best route. When I was told it was really opinionated I realized I just had to go with what I thought worked best.

Comment: I ma glad that you found a solution. It is ok to accept your on answer. In fact, we prefer it, because doing so will help others who read this in future. just click the tick to the left. It might still be worth looking at Flutter, though. Btw, [Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) and C++ Builder will do the same. You use a Windows desktop app to develop native code for all platforms from a single code base. Rapid Application Development makes things really quick and a compiled language, rather than scripted, really helps. Ask me, if you want to know more ..  Good luck :-).